# Export to excel in angularjs using Blob

Tags: excel, angularjs, blob

I'm exporting a dataset to excel in angularjs.

Sample code snippet

---

```
dataValue += '<tr><td>'+item.ProfName+'</td>'
      +'<td>'+item.Used+'</td>'
      +'<td>'+item.DateUsed+'</td>'
      +'<td>'+item.TId+'</td>'
      +'<td>'+item.SId+'</td>'
      +'<td>'+OFFER.o_status[item.Status]+'</td></tr>';
dataValue += '</table>';
// Upto here is fine in safari
var blob = new Blob([''+dataValue+''], {
    type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
});
saveAs(blob, "Offer_"+o_id+".xls");
```

---

This works absolutely fine in chrome and firefox however in safari it's not working

Seems like the issue is with the Blob.

Anyone having any clue on this.

Thanks for reading,
Uttam

Answer (score 0):

There is a polyfill for Blob. https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js/